# Node.js debugging - cannot attach debugger subprocesses

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Basically I am having trouble attaching the VS Code debugger to the subprocesses I have in my Node app.  It only attaches to the master process.

I have already read and followed the official documentation here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_automatically-attach-debugger-to-nodejs-subprocesses

My Node code uses the cluster module to fork a few worker.  Pretty standard really and it follows the cluster example code.

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master process ${process.pid} starting...`);
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs && i < maxNumThreads; i++) {
        cluster.fork(); // Create a worker
    }
} else {
    startClusterWorkers();
}

function startClusterWorkers() {
    // xxxxxx
}
```

And my launch.json already has autoAttachChildProcesses defined.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch app.js",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.js",
            "restart": true,
            "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
            // "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch test.js",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\test.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the child processes don't show up in the call stack or the floating debugger control, unlike the official documentation.  The debugger console doesn't say anything about the child processes either.  And of course breakpoints set in the child process (the `startClusterWorkers()` function above) don't work.

```
Debugging with inspector protocol because Node.js v8.9.1 was detected.
node --inspect-brk=31761 app.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:31761/54919117-38ae-4455-82c6-e21ade314bdd
Master process 10096 starting...
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong please?

VS Code ver 1.20.1 (latest)
Node ver 8.9.1

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a bug -

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45320

It's fixed in Insiders now and should be in stable soon.